# including the datediff expression within the table in a row in MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a 3 column in my table as start date, end date and total days. All I need it the following

How to set the current date in the start date column
Another question is how to get the date difference and the result should be displayed in another column called total days.

Comment: what have you tried? Access DateDiff function can be found here http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php

Comment: Use the query design window to at least get started.

Answer (score 0):

The start date can be set so that the default value is the current date, date(), when a record is created.  You do that in design window.  Since the other two fields are clearly filled in at a later date the mechanism for input can use the same function as a default end date.  The difference is then calculated between current date and start date.  If you use a form as the mechanism for update, the expressions are set as default values.  If you use an update query, those expressions would be set as the updating values.